# Subtraction/difference between bytes in Java

Tags: java, byte

I'm trying to subtract one byte from another while making sure no overflow happens, but get unexpected results.

My case is that I have an byte black and white image, of which I want to subtract the background. Hence I need to work with bytes and prevent overflows from happening. I have some difficulty presumably with the signedness of the bytes when subtracting the background image from the other image. Data2 is the background array, and data1 is the other image.

In the following code, I expect data2 array to be subtracted from data1 array. However I get low values when I am sure there should be high ones.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
        if (data1[i] > data2[i]) {
            dest[i] = (byte) (data1[i] - data2[i]);
        } else {
            dest[i] = 0;
        }
    }
```

I figured I should make sure data2 byte isn't negative and being added to data1.
So I came to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
        if (data1[i] > data2[i]) {

            dest[i] = (byte) ((int)data1[i] & 0xff - (int)data2[i] & 0xff - 128);

        } else {
            dest[i] = 0;
        }
    }
```

However this also doesn't give the right results.

My thoughts on this currently are:

```
(byte) ((int)data1[i] & 0xff - (int)data2[i] & 0xff - 128);

(int) cast: make sure bytes are cast to integer.
&0xff: make value unsigned.
- subtraction smaller value from bigger value.
- 128: subtract 128 to make signed again.
(byte): cast back to byte.
```

I hope I'm doing something stupidly wrong here, or my problem resides somewhere else of which I can't figure out where.

**Edit**

I seem to have figured out a part of the issue:
data1[i] > data2[i] is handled wrong (in my case) when the bytes are signed. Instead:

```
        if ((data1[i] & 0xff) > (data2[i] & 0xff)) {
```

seems to produce the right results, instead of the previous comparison.

Comment: How can you be sure there is no overflow? -125-126 = ?

Comment: Because -125 is smaller than 126 and that should result in dest[i] = 0;

Comment: I figured I needed to add the sign back, it was a desperate attempt. I posted an answer with the code that does work. If someone can explain what is happening, I'll mark that as answer as I have no idea why this situation occurs. I expect signed bytes to be comparable like signed ints, but the behaviour seems to be different.

Comment: @RobotRock it's not weird. 0xF0 is -16 in Java - check my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point here is that your bytes come from an API that uses 8 bits to encode the light of the pixel, so they range `0; 0xFF`. However Java bytes are `-128; 127`, so any bit pattern after `0x7F` will be interpreted as a negative number. For example the bits in `0xF0` are `128` if the byte is unsigned and `-16` if interpreted as a signed byte:

```
System.out.println(0xFF > 0);  // true
System.out.println((byte) 0xFF > 0); // false
```

So when comparing your unsigned bytes you want to promote pixels to `int` with `Byte.toUnsignedInt(byteVal)` (or `((int) byteVal) & 0xFF` on Java 7).

Comment: Doesn't "byteVal & 0xff" convert byteVal to integer and then mask it? Either way, (int)byteVal & 0xff doesn't result in different behaviour.

Comment: @RobotRock part of the problem is that you're casting back to a `byte` after you do the subtraction.

Comment: Guess what `System.out.println((byte) 200)` prints? Your mask has no effect because you don't work with bits here, but perform a regular addition

Comment: @RobotRock I think you are wasting your time. Better explain why you have bytes, what you want to do with them and what you need to return

Comment: I'll add my case to the original post.

Comment: @RobotRock use Byte.toUnsigedInt before the subtraction, then cast to byte. Before subtraction, you may want to add an assertion that the result will be positive or zero

Comment: Byte.toUnsignedInt is not available for me as I'm not using Java SE 8, but 7.

Comment: Ah okay, I was using byteVal & 0xff which should be the same.

Comment: The cast to int is necessary because you want a positive number. Otherwise it may be less than zero

Comment: F0 is 240 actually, not 128, isn't it?

Comment: Also can you try comparing bytes and see if they produce the right outputs, so byteval1 > byteval2, and print that?

Comment: Already done. Check the update. The > operator doesn't know your bytes are unsigned

Comment: Ah, I get it now. I wasnt taking into account the sign bit is actually available and is MSB. Yes, that explains the weird results and why making the comparison unsigned worked as the byte are originally unsigned. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Always remember Java bytes are signed.  If `data1[i]` is `127`, and `data2[i]` is `-128`, then `data1[i] > data2[i]`, but `data1[i] - data2[i]` does not fit into a signed `byte`; that result is 255.

If you *treat* the bytes as unsigned, that's fine.  That more-or-less means printing them out after using `& 0xFF`, and such.  That will work just fine; it will give the right results *if* you treat them as unsigned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that you only substract non negative bytes from from bytes that are greater you should use :

```
for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    if (data1[i] > data2[i] && data2[i]>=0 ) {
        dest[i] = (byte) (data1[i] - data2[i]);
    } else {
        dest[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Your second code does not work because the & operator promotes the values to type int.
Consider the case where data1=127 (0x7F) and data2=-128 (0x80).
`data1 & 0xff` is type int and has value 127 (0x0000007F)
`data2 & 0xff` is type int and has value 128 (0x00000080)
`data1[i] & 0xff - data2[i] & 0xff` is type int and has value -1 (0xFFFFFFFF)
`(byte)(data1[i] & 0xff - data2[i] & 0xff)` is type byte and has value -1 (0xFF)
So you still have gotten an overflow

Comment: You are correct about the overflow. I hadn't added it yet, but it has crossed my mind. I tried subtracting 128 after initial subtraction, which should prevent overflow (or was it 127?), but that didn't work out either.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, comparing bytes is handled weirdly. If I convert the bytes to unsigned ints in the comparison, the comparison works correctly and my results are as I expected them.

I can then subtract the bytes as if they were unsigned as Louis Wasserman pointed out, which was new to me.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
        if ((data1[i] & 0xff) > (data2[i] & 0xff)) {
            dest[i] = (byte)(data1[i] - data2[i]);
        } else {
            dest[i] = 0;
        }
    }
```